# What is wrong with my understanding of switch statements?

Tags: java

Logically, I would think the answer should be 0. The print out is 2.

```
public class Switch{
public static void main(String[] args){

int x = 3; int y = 4;

  switch (x + 3) {
    case 6: y = 0;
    case 7: y = 1; 
    default: y += 1;
   }
System.out.print(y);
}
}
```

This is how I would think the code should run:

1) add x + 3. The answer is 6.

2) case 6 correlates with answer 6. This results in 0 being the new value for 6.

3) we ignore case 7 and default because case 6 fit the needs.

4) System prints out the new value for y, which is 0.

This is where I am wrong, because 2 is printed out. Where is my thinking wrong, and what am I missing in my understanding about switch statements?

Comment: You missed `break` statements.

Comment: `javac` will warn you about these fallthroughs if you pass the `-Xlint` option.

Comment: Since you don't have any `break;`, you'll visit each `case`. In the first case `y` is 0, then it's 1, then it's 2 and that's the returned value.

Comment: Typically IDE's can also produce a warning for missing break statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a Case in a Switch statement is selected, code execution is just straight down from there, which means that it´s executing all of the cases. If you don´t want that, use Break statements:

```
switch (x + 3) {
    case 6: y = 0; break;
    case 7: y = 1; break;
    default: y += 1; break;
   }
```

Comment: There's no need to add `break` for the `default` case

Comment: @ChristopherBabayans If you are satisfied with the answer, then mark it as accepted. It will make the navigators that this question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

In a `switch` you "fall through" the cases, starting from the one matched. So here, you enter `case 6`, then `case 7` and then `default`. This behavior can be prevented with the `break` keyword:

```
switch (x + 3) {
    case 6: 
        y = 0;
        break;
    case 7:
        y = 1; 
        break;
    default:
        y += 1;
        break;
}
```